# Data operation in memory

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, data-management

I know it is always better to operate data in memory instead of file. Currently, I am putting all incoming data in a static ArrayList, and when that ArrayList has more than 80 entries, my program will save the contents of this ArrayList to a file and clear up this array for the next wave of coming data.

I wonder if it's better (or worse) to use Vector instead of ArrayList. If there is difference, which is better/worse? And in which case?

Here is my relevant code:

```
public class Exchange () {
    private static ArrayList<String> datain = new ArrayList<String> ();
    public static void addData(String s) {
        datain.add(s);
    }

    public static boolean checkSize() {
        if (datain.size() >= 80)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void writeData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File ("myfile.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < datain.size(); i++) {
            pw.println(datain.get(i);
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        datain = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

P.S. This approach currently works fine, I am just wondering whether using vector will be better for this case. Also, if you see any bad design, feel free to point it out. Thanks!

Comment: Note: your `checkSize()` method could simply do `return datain.size() >= 80;`. Try to avoid `if(condition) return true; else return false;`

Comment: You can use `Exchanger` for this sort of thing.  Writing 80 lines at a time or one line 80x will take the same amount of time.

Comment: Are you expecting to append, or overwrite?

Comment: I also fail to understand your logic: each time writeData() is called, it replaces the entries currently in the file by the one in the list.

Comment: If you are happy to discard your lines every so often, could you just avoid writing anything.

Comment: @Zouzou: Is there any particular reason why I should avoid using if/else condition in this?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, I have another class taking care of backing up the "myfile.txt". I am thinking of using this class for auto-backup purpose.

Comment: @BallroomProgrammer if your condition is evaluated to true, you return true else you return false. So just return the value of the condition direclty.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a `String[]` if you know the exact capacity...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, using `ArrayList` will suffice. The primary difference is that `Vector` is thread-safe, whilst `ArrayList` is not, but seeing as you aren't working with multiple threads, there is no reason to prefer `Vector` over `ArrayList` in your code

Comment: Vector is also a legacy class which was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998)

Comment: Unless you want a synchronized implementation, but even then you're almost always better off doing your synchronization in a different way

Comment: @user3580294: if you want a synchronized implementation, similar to Vector, you just need `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())`

Comment: Which is why I said you're almost always better off doing your synchronization in a different way

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, unless I know there is a performance issue.  Most of the cost is in the opening and closing of the file, so I would avoid doing that.  I would also assume that appending is what you want.

```
public enum Logging {
    ; // no instances
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "myfile.txt";
    private static final PrintWriter pw;

    static {
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, true));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new AssertionError(ioe);
        }
    }

    public static void addData(String s) {
        pw.println(s);
    }
}
```